# react native app auth google oauth redirect url

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to use `FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth` in my react native android app. I have created google oauth client id in google developer console as a web application. I have a problem adding correct redirect url in the console. As i have read the redirect url for android applications should look like something like this `com.testapp.app:/oauth` but these type of urls cannot be added in the google developer console. So how should i add it ?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.testchat.app" android:host="heybuddyapp/callback"/>
</intent-filter>
```

is the scheme correct or should it be changed ?

**build.gradle**

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    manifestPlaceholders = [
        appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.testchat.app:/heybuddyapp/callback'
    ]
}
```

**config of react native app auth**

```
const config = {
  issuer: 'https://accounts.google.com',
  clientId: 'ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  redirectUrl: 'com.testchat.app:/heybuddyapp/callback',
  scopes: [
    'openid',
    'profile'
  ],
};
```

How should be the redirect url in the above sections ? And how should it be on the google developer console ?

Any help would be appreciated !

[image: google developer console redirect url]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future readers.. I have figured out the answer. I was using web application in the google developer console create credentials section, but it should be Android instead. After adding the **Signing-certificate fingerprint** reference - [react native sign apk](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android) Then you should add your package name as in the AndroidManifest.xml (example - `com.testapp.app`) Then in the `android\app\build.gradle` file add

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    manifestPlaceholders = [
        appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.testapp.app' //this line
    ]
}
```

And if you are usging `FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth` package, config should be like this

```
const config = {
  issuer: 'https://accounts.google.com',
  clientId: 'ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  redirectUrl: 'com.testapp.app:/oauth2callback',
  scopes: [
    'openid',
    'profile'
  ],
};
```

And that's it !